# javascript: validate form element if it is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

i want to validate input during form submit for textbox B if it is enabled by radio 2.
The input validation for textbox B is not working with the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#form").validate(
    {
        rules: {B: "required",}
    }); 

   ​$(':radio').change(function() 
   {
        $('#B').prop('disabled', !(this.value == '2' && this.checked));
   })​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;         
});
</script>

<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
<table><tr>
<td width><input type="radio" name="A" id="1" value="1" />1</td>
<td width><input type="radio" name="A" id="2" value="2" />2</td>
</tr></table>
<input name="B" type="text" id="B" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="submit" name="form" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle so we can see it in action?

Comment: @Xymostech, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/newbie_85/R6qDa/ . But it is somehow not working. i'd just created my account in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                B: "required",
            }
        });
    $('input:radio[name="A"]').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '2') {
            $('#B').removeAttr('disabled');
        }else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '1'){
            $('#B').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it's working now...  But after i select the radio 2, then select back to radio 1, the textbox B is still enable. how to make it to be disabled again when radio 1 is selected?

Comment: you haven't mentioned that in your question that you want it disabled back

Comment: I have added the necessary code into the current answer try it out

Comment: Your are very helpful. Thanks for your effort ;)